# Multiple Array "Merge" into 1 with different structure

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
Table 1: StudentDB
UserID(PK)   REGID  Username   Password    Timelog        Status
   1           1       tom        123       12/08/2019    Active
   2           2       ben        544       13/08/2019    Active
Table 2: UpdateDB
REGID  UpdateStatus  Timelog               Remark
  1        Updated     14/08/2019      UpdatePassword
  2        Updated     15/08/2019      UpdatePassword
  1        Updated     17/08/2019      UpdatePassword
  2        Updated     25/08/2019      UpdatePassword
Table 3: suspendDB
REGID  SuspendStatus Timelog               Remark
  1        Suspended   20/08/2019       Acc Suspended
```

Above is my 3 Different Table Structure.

```
$data['REGData'] = $this->user->SearchREG($REGID);
$data['updateData'] = $this->user->SearchUpdate($REGID);
$data['suspendData'] = $this->user->SearchSuspend($REGID);
```

Above is my controller.

What i want: 
"Merge" all my row into a new array with pre-fix column name

How i do make a new array with these data

```
$data['REGData'] = $this->user->SearchREG($REGID); (Retrieve Username)
$data['updateData'] = $this->user->SearchUpdate($REGID);  (Retreive Update Status and Timelog)
$data['suspendData'] = $this->user->SearchSuspend($REGID); (Retrieve suspend and Timelog)


REGID => REGID,
Username => Username,
Timelog => Timelog ,
Action Status => Update/Suspend
```

What i wanted (Result) (to show at view page)

```
REGID           Username       Timelog       ActionStatus
1                 tom          14/08/2019       UpdatePassword
2                 ben          15/08/2019       UpdatePassword
1                 tom          17/08/2019       UpdatePassword
1                 tom          20/08/2019       Acc Suspended
2                 ben          25/08/2019       UpdatePassword
```

Comment: Unclear what exactly you want. Please provide an example of input data and expected output.

Comment: @misorude added in first post , sorry was updating and misclick on "post"

Comment: So loop over the data from UpdateDB, and loop over the data from suspendDB, and put both into an array (so you can sort them by Timelog), and then loop over that array, and go “look up” the user name in the records you fetched from the StudentDB, via the REGID value while doing so …

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through loops in the codeigniter layer, you may want draft your own query to do that instead. It'll scale better.

Just select rows of users along with their update and suspend actions and `UNION` all of them since they share the same structure.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select u.REGID, st.Username, u.Timelog, u.Remark AS ActionStatus FROM updatedb AS u
        JOIN studentdb AS st ON st.REGID = u.REGID

        UNION ALL

    select s.REGID, st.Username, s.Timelog, s.Remark AS ActionStatus FROM suspenddb AS s
        JOIN studentdb AS st ON st.REGID = s.REGID
) t

ORDER BY t.Timelog ASC
```